# CISCO refuses to turn off spanning tree for specific vlans

Tags: configuration, cisco

I have a cisco c1000-48p-4g-L that has the following global config line.

```
no spanning-tree vlan 60,70,99,110,207,221,242,455-461,510,666,700,702,705,900
```

when attempting the below config command:
`spanning-tree vlan 99`

the cisco accepts the command, but when we look at the config again, it still shows 99 in the no spanning-tree config line.

What are we missing?
thanks!